# this.form.submit() still fires after code is removed

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net-mvc-3, html-helper

Problem:
What I want to do is have a form submit event fire when I exit a text box that I've added to a view.

Details:
I have a view in an MVC application which I've added three text boxes to the bottom of the view.  Before this addition, I had an Html helper textarea that fired the this.form.submit when I tabbed out of it:

```
<%=Html.TextAreaFor(r => r.Notes, new { @class = "textAreaNoScroll", @onblur = "this.form.submit();"} })%>
```

Before the change, this was the last control at the bottom of the page.  I've cut the code @onblur... and pasted it in, what is now, the last control:

```
<%=Html.TextBoxFor(acc => acc.AccountNumber, new { @onblur = "this.form.submit();"}) %>
```

But when I debug now the view still does the submit on the textarea with the id 'r.Notes'.

Fixes:
Firstly, I check the markup in 'View Source' from the browser (Chrome).  The changes are correct.  I cleared my browser cache but this made no difference.  Here's the relevent code segment:

```
 <asp:Panel ID="pnlProcessingInstructions" runat="server">            
            <table class="displayBox-topBottom">
                <tr>
                    <td class="labels displayInput_noWidth">Processing Notes</td>
                    <td class="labels displayInput_noWidth">Instructions</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <%if (Model != null && Model.PaymentDayId != -1)
                      { %>
                        <td><%=Html.TextAreaFor(r => r.ProcessingNotes, new { @class = "textAreaNoScroll" })%></td>
                    <%}
                      else
                      {%>
                        <td><%=Html.TextAreaFor(r => r.ProcessingNotes, new { @class = "textAreaNoScroll" })%></td>
                    <%}%>
                    <td><%=Html.TextAreaFor(r => r.Notes, new { @class = "textAreaNoScroll" })%></td> <!-- FORMER LAST CONTROL -->
                </tr>              
                <tr>
                    <td><span id = "ProcessingCharsLeft" class="smallerFont">1,000</span> characters left</td>
                    <td><span id = "CharsLeft" class="smallerFont">1,000</span> characters left</td>
                </tr>
            </table>
            </asp:Panel>
           </fieldset>
           <fieldset>
        <legend class="labels"> Payment Details</legend>

          <asp:Panel ID="pnlPaymentDetails" runat="server">            
            <table class="displayBox-topBottom">
                <tr>
                    <td class="labels displayInput_noWidth">Institution</td>
                    <td class="labels displayInput_noWidth">Transit</td>
                    <td class="labels displayInput_noWidth">Account Number</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><%=Html.TextBoxFor(i => i.Institution) %></td>
                    <td><%=Html.TextBoxFor(tr => tr.TransitNumber) %></td>
                    <td><%=Html.TextBoxFor(acc => acc.AccountNumber, new { @onblur = "this.form.submit();"}) %></td> <!-- NEW LAST CONTROL -->
                </tr>
                </table>
               </asp:Panel>
```

It never gets past 'r.Notes' and acts as if 'this.form.submit' is still part of the control.  Again, I've cleared the cache and rebuilt my solution. How can 'this.form.submit()' be firing on a control where the code doesn't exist?

Answer (score 2):

OK, I figured it out.  A previous page is using the same Model element 'r.Notes'.  This page has the form.submit event and this is what triggers the submit on the page I'm editing.  I renamed the textareafor to a html.textArea control and renamed it to MyNotes as an id and it doesn't submit.

Comment: +1 for good practice to post the answer if you found out the problem.